# Get a field's value

Tags: java, reflection, field

I want to get the value with which the field is being **initialized**.
Example:

```
class ClassA {
  public String someString = "Merry Christmas";
}

class ClassB {
 String anotherString = ClassA.class.getField("someString");
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: `new ClassA().someString`

Comment: This is just an example. I'm creating a settings system with annotations so I only have the field available in my settingsManager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be possible if `ClassA.string` were `static`. In this case you would be able to get the value through *reflection* without the need to get a hold of an *instance* of `ClassA` inside of which `someString` is defined:

```
class ClassA {
  public static String someString = "Merry Christmas";
}
...
Object s = ClassA.class.getField("someString").get(null);
```

[Demo 1.](http://ideone.com/tje2Fw)

If the variable is *not* static, and you simply want to get its initial value, you could still do it, assuming that `ClassA` has a default constructor:

```
public static void demo(Class<?> cl) throws Exception {
    Object s = cl.getField("someString").get(cl.newInstance());
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

[Demo 2.](http://ideone.com/KgK41S)

Comment: I'm now giving the Class in which someString is located as Class<?> to ClassB. How can i create a new object from that Class<?> ?

Comment: @MyNameIsHans If you have a variable `cl` of type `Class<?>`, you can do `cl.getField("someString").get(null)`.

Comment: Yes. but I want `someString` to stay non-static that's why I have to create a new `object` of `cl`. (I need the value with which `someString` was initialized)

Comment: Ok. I have very many `instances` of this class and other `classes` that use `ClassB`. So always creating a new `instance` would be kind of inefficient. Is there a way to just create one "default class" of each type of `class` and store them in a `static` `map` or something like this and then use these `classes` to get the default value of `someString`/other `object`s.

Comment: @MyNameIsHans Absolutely! You can make a `Map<Class<?>,String> cachedStrings` and a method that checks `cachedStrings` for a given class, before creating an instance and harvesting the initial value of `someString`.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You first have to create an instance o `ClassA` into `ClassB`:

`ClassA a = new ClassA();
System.out.println(a.someString);`

But according to the current format of your code, the best option would be declaring `someString` static: `public static String someString = "Merry Christmas";`. Then you can directly access this field from any other class of any package (as it's public):  
`System.out.println(ClassA.someString);`

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not fully understand what a (non-`static`) field means: it means the field has a **specific value** for each instance (object) of `ClassA`, so you cannot access the fields content, because there can be thousands, each with a different value.

There are several options:

A possible solution is to make the field `static`:

```
ClassA {
    public static String someString = "Merry Christmas";
}

ClassB {
    String anotherString = ClassA.someString;
}
```

Or as @toubou says, you can construct an object and access the field of that specific object. Note however that fields represent an object's state, and therefore can modify.

Comment: Could the dv'er please explain what is wrong with this answer?